# Is the set of functions between two arbitrarily close L^1 functions closed?

Tags: integration

Let $(X, {\cal \tau}, \mu)$ be a probability space
and $F$ some vector subspace of integrable functions (defined everywhere). I can look at the set
$$\hat{F} = \{f \hbox{ integrable } \mid \forall \varepsilon>0, \ \exists \,g,h \in F \hbox{ such that }
g \leq f \leq h \hbox{ and } \int h-g < \varepsilon\}$$

Is $\hat{F}$ the closure or the completion of $F$ for some topology? If so, which one? Does it come from a distance or a norm?

Note that this is not the completion with respect to the $L^1$ norm in general.
Such extension occurs for example in Riemann integration,
in the proof of the Weyl criterion
for equidistribution or in the portmanteau theorem in probability.

Comment: Are a.e. functions identified in $L^1(X)$? And if so, is the inequality $g \leq f \leq h$ understood a.e.?

Comment: Good point. The space $F$ should be a subspace of Borel integrable functions without identification, in order to define $\hat{F}$ with inequality holding everywhere.

Comment: What if you define $d(f,f') = \inf \int h-g$ where the inf is taken over $\{(g,h)\in F^2: g \leq f-f' \leq h\}$? This probably defines a pseudometric.

Comment: This is a good idea. I will try to sort it out. Still I am surprised that it has not a well known answer.

Comment: uh... my previous comment is a bit facetious. (It is not that useful since the pseudometric itself now depends on the set F, so is not external to the set F as what I am guessing you would prefer.)